# screen not starting on iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios

I am starting an iPhone application, and I can't seem to get the main screen started. Here is my delegate.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainViewController;

@end
```

and here is my implementation file(at least the beginning):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize mainViewController = _mainViewController;


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_mainViewController];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

MainViewController *aViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[self setMainViewController:aViewController];
[aViewController release];

self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

When I try to run the app, just a black screen appears, and even after waiting a long time, the screen won't show the contents of my MainViewController.xib file...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you connected the `window` property in your XIB?

Comment: How would I do that? I opened the MainViewController.xib, the I opened the AppDelegate.h, and tried to connect the xib to the UIWindow, but the was not highlighting for a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main XIB of your application is MainWindow.xib. (It can be selected in project settings).
It contains app delegate, window and mainViewController (BTW, it should be better connected from XIB, not created manually in application:didFinishLaunching) connected  to app delegate.
Check the connections.